# FullScreen in the Background

Tags: background, desktop-application, fullscreen

Im curious if their is a way to make a windows application ( in c# or any language really ) run in fullscreen in the background.

But still allow other applications to run on top of it without losing the fullscreen view.

Any leads would be appreciated.

**Edit: Unmarked the answer to see what else i could get. While the original was helpful, im curious for other methods.**

Comment: +1 Interesting question. What would you use this feature to accomplish?

Comment: I thought it would be kinda cool if i could make kinda like little pseduo OS interface to run on top of the current, that way i could like design it to be how i want. Limited idea and efficiency, but a cool project to work on imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm a bit surprised not to see any answers yet.)

You can query the size of the desktop and make your application exactly that size, and then put it under the other windows on the screen. The details of all of that will depend on what you end up using to write it.

For instance, in C#:

- The size of the desktop is available from the [`WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx) property of the [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8xzhd15.aspx) object for the primary display. You get the `Screen` object for the primary display via [`Screen.PrimaryScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen.aspx).
- The [`Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx) class will help you with the other stuff, like the `Width` and `Height` properties, etc.

Marking this answer CW because it seems very half-baked, but it's a start. Anyone feel free to add to it.